# How to merge two maps in C++ such that the values of the same keys are added, otherwise created?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers

I think the title is pretty clear, this is an example of what I want to achieve it without having to iterate over the keys and add them manually, I was wondering if there exist a faster solution ( some function or a technique... )

Example :

```
std::map<int,int> a, b, c;
a[0] = 2;
a[2] = 5;
b[0] = 6;
b[1] = 1;
```

and the result is a map c that contains :

```
std::cout << c[0] << std::endl; // prints 8
std::cout << c[1] << std::endl; // prints 1
std::cout << c[2] << std::endl; // prints 5
```

in brief :

```
if key exists : add the values
else create it with the current value
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. How is this question too broad? "Merge two maps but instead of omitting duplicates (like `std::map::merge`), add them together".

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ignore my last comment, I misread the edit history.

Comment: Does `c` have to be an actual `std::map`, or can it be a custom class that is read only?

Comment: Any answer will *require* iterating over the maps in some way. If *"without having to iterate over the keys"* is to be taken literally, there is no solution. If you just mean you don't want to write a `for` loop, then where do you draw the line? Is `std::for_each` allowed? Edit : I guess if you want to get technical, you could iterate over the values (which is the same thing for a `std::map`) but I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean that I wonder if there exists a solution that doesn't take linear time ...

Comment: @MooingDuck doesn't really matter if its significantely faster.

Comment: @NouemanKhalikine You might get linear time, at best, since the maps are sorted.

Comment: @NouemanKhalikine Have you given any thought to whether sublinear time might be impossible?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Not really... I guess I'll have to use a different data structure optimized for this kind of tasks... probably not possible with std::map under linear time..

Comment: @NouemanKhalikine If you want to take an action for every item in the second map (there's no specification that they can't all exist already in the first map and thus need an addition), you _need to touch every item_... No data structure will give you sublinear time for doing that.

Comment: Good question closed for no reason.

Comment: [Lazy work for you?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c6d7fcd98aa5a17)

Answer (score 4):

> this is an example of what I want to achieve it without having to iterate over the keys and add them manually,

I don't think you can accomplish your objective without iterating over the contents of the maps.

The simplest method I can think of is the following:

```
c = a;
for ( auto const& item : b )
{
   c[item.first] += item.second;
}
```